# QQuickWindow transparent

Tags: qt

im using QQmlApplicationEngine with QQuickWindow for an application and i can't
transparent main window. i want to set a splash before application pops up and i use Window component for it and it should be transparent but it's not, my main.cpp is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Application app(argc, argv);

QShookaClient shooka_client;
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("shooka", &shooka_client);
engine.load(QUrl("qrc:///shooka/shooka.qml"));

QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

window->show();
window->setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
window->setColor(Qt::transparent);

return app.exec();
}
```

but setColor doesn't work in win7. i know there is way for QDeclarativeView or even i found solution for QQuickview and it kinda should work for QQuickWindow but no, can anyone help me please..

Comment: A QWindow is not the same as a QWidget. The ...View classes all derive from a QWidget.

Answer (score 8):

One has to realize that a `Window` QtQuick type maps to `QQuickWindow` C++ class, and derives from `QWindow`. The window flags, per Cameron's answer, can be set. But you also need to set the `opacity` to, say, 0.75 to make it translucent. All of this can be done in QML, no need for setting flags from C++.

[image: screenshot]

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    flags: Qt.SubWindow | Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
    opacity: 0.75
    visible: true
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }
    Button {
        text: "Hello World"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: you know. i did what u told me but it didn work:D i dont know whats wrong with win7 or sth i just did wrong. but i also just copy and paste your code in mine and the program was running and the task was in taskmanager but nothing on my screen... do u have any idea?

Comment: I haven't tested it under Windows 7. Do you use angle or opengl build of Qt under Win7?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but as it is not marked as solved, here is my approach:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    color: "transparent"
    visible: true
    Rectangle
    {
        color:"red"
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height/2;anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

As result, you will get a transparent background with a red rectangle in the middle. You could easily change that rectangle for an image.

Hope helped someone.

Comment: This reply should be marked as correct solution. I had the exact same issue, and that one did it (which makes sense, too). Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the following code for achieving a frameless transparent window effect:

```
setWindowFlags(
        #ifdef Q_OS_MAC
            Qt::SubWindow |
        #else
            Qt::Tool |
        #endif
            Qt::FramelessWindowHint |
            Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint |
            Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint
        );

setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
// set the parent widget's background to translucent
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);

setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
// create a display widget for displaying child widgets
QWidget* displayWidget = new QWidget;
displayWidget->setStyleSheet(".QWidget { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 75%); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 10px; border-color: #555555; } .QWidget:hover { background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 75%); border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 10px; border-color: #ffffff; }");
```

The idea is that your parent window or containing window has no frame and has a translucent background. Then you nest a child QWidget inside the parent QWidget and apply styles using QSS for transparency.

Comment: tanx Cameron, but the problem is QWindow is not the same as QWidget. im not an expert in qt and i know they must related somhow...but realy how??? and QQuickWindow does not even have Attribute to be set like QWidget or anything drive from QQuickView...